# intval or is_numeric? PHP

Tags: php, isnumeric

i am fetching a text from mysql database and i get it by ID in the url:

site.php?id=1 and so on

What is considered to be most safe to prevent sql injection and stuff. Is this way correct:

```
<?php
$news_id = $_GET['news_id'];

if(!is_numeric($news_id)) die('Wrong');

//mysql_query and stuff here
?>
```

OR this way:

```
<?php
$news_id = $_GET['news_id'];

if(!intval($news_id)) die('Wrong');

//mysql_query and stuff here
?>
```

Comment: A little note to is_numeric, it allows hexidecimal character (not such a big deal security-wise seen). If you really like to check for a numeric value, use ctype_digit, make sure to enter a string, not an int:

ctype_digit ( (int) 123 ); // false
ctype_digit ( '123' ); // true

Answer (score 6):

Why not just use a prepared statement, which is the correct way to deal with sql injection attacks.

But, use intval to turn the string into an integer, and then just put that into your prepared statement, and you will be protected, as, the int value may be a zero or negative so nothing will be returned from your query.

Answer (score 3):

```
$news_id = (int)@$_GET['news_id'];
if ($news_id <= 0) die ('Wrong');
```

Assuming `news_id` is positive (>0).

Answer (score 1):

If you use intval you won't be able to use news_id=0, because intval will always return 0 if news_id isn't a number.
is_numeric is more suitable and safer in your case.

Comment: Chances are, `news_id` is a generated column that will never contain 0. If that's the case, then there's no harm in using intval( $id ) in the query; if the request contained a bad identifier, then you'll end up displaying a "not found" error, which is perfectly acceptable for a bad request. Alternatively, of course, if 0 is a value that's never used, then you can test the output and throw up a different error ("please provide a valid identifier") rejecting the request.

Answer (score 0):

is_numeric is not a good way to check it,

```
$number = "4"; // string ? int ?
```

intval doesn't return true or false. so you can't use it like you wrote.
try this one

```
if(intval($news_id) === (int)$news_id){
//code goes here
}
```

or

```
if(intval($news_id) == $news_id){
//code goes here
}
```

Comment: What is the legal range of numbers for your id? Does it start with zero or one?

Comment: this answer is totally wrong there is no such function as int_val

Comment: @Traveling_Monk Cool down, i meant intval but there's just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/^[1-9]+\d*$/", $news_id)){
    // you're good to go
}
```

Comment: This excludes leading `0`s, including "0".  Is that intentional?  Also, the `+` is not useful.